# How to display ads from two adsense accounts with time Interval?

Tags: javascript, adsense

I want to display ads of two adsense accounts on a website with time intervals.

Popular hosted services like Wikidot and some forum service providers practice this to share revenue between clients. Say a user 'U' creates an account on a hosted platform. He adds his adsense code(his own publisher ID) on the subsite. Then ads from his adsense account appears with some time interval (say 5 min) and the hosted service's ads(Ads of their Publisher ID) for another 5 minutes.

Likewise, the two ad-sense advertisements execution will be changed by time. I have no expertise in Java script and I am not sure how to make that work.

Could anybody help me to achieve it? I can do it with some help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Javascript**

```
function TimeFunction()
{

var d = new Date();

var m=d.getMinutes();
m = m%10
if (m < 6)
{
    alert("5 or les");
}
else
{
    alert('6 or moer');
}

 }
```

Code to test

```
  <a onClick="TimeFunction();" style="cursor: pointer; cursor: hand;">*click here*</a>
```

//**Updated Now it works**